# Search filter has to filter from [[String: Any]]() array to new filtered array?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a `tableview` where I am loading all the details from the array which I have named `PlaylistArray` . I having a search page where user can search the from the `playlistArray` which of type `[[String: Any]]`. I don't know how to filter the search text given by the user in that `PlayListArray` to `filteredArray`. I have attached the `PlaylistArray` response for your reference.

This is the code which I have tried before for filtering the `PlaylistArray`.

```
 let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
 let array = (constantsList.playTypeArray.lectureArraymp3 as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)
          //  filtered_Array.add(array)
 print(array)
```

I need to search the search text provided by the user and we have to compare the search text to the `title` tag of `playlistArray`. when both are same I need to show the entire details of the particular array index to the filtered array.

**PlaylistArray:**

```
[["title": Kaṭha-Bhāṣyam-41 Mantra 1-2-20, "image_url": https://www.imaginetventures.name/swamijione/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gitanew.png, "mp3": https://www.imaginetventures.name/swamiji/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/01-PURU],["title": Kaṭha-Bhāṣyam-41 Mantra 1-2-20, "image_url": https://www.imaginetventures.name/swamijione/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gitanew.png, "mp3": https://www.imaginetventures.name/swamiji/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/01-PURU],["title": Kaṭha-Bhāṣyam-41 Mantra 1-2-20, "image_url": https://www.imaginetventures.name/swamijione/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gitanew.png, "mp3": https://www.imaginetventures.name/swamiji/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/01-PURU]]
```

Comment: provide sample array data and expected a result for more clarity.

Comment: posted the sample array data , expected data has to in the same format but the "Filteredarray" should have only values similar to search text entered .

Comment: All the titles are same or it is just an example ?

Comment: For eg: if search text = "Kar" then the filtered array should have the array values whose title has the caracters similar to "Kar". "title" you can find it from "PlaylistArray"

Comment: No not all the titles are same its just an example

Comment: in real case it will be different

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for swift using `filter` API. Read more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter

```
let array = [["title": "Kaṭha-Bhāṣyam-41 Mantra 1-2-20", "image_url": "https://www.imaginetventures.name/swamijione/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gitanew.png"],
             ["title": "Kaṭa-Bhāṣyam-41 Mantra 1-2-20", "image_url": "https://www.imaginetventures.name/swamijione/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/gitanew.png"]]

guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else {return} //Or use if-let
let filteredArray = array.filter { (object) -> Bool in
    guard let title = object["title"] as? String else {return false}
    return title?.contains(searchText) ?? false
}
```

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array of dictionaries use an array of structs. Create a struct and struct instances

```
//Item
struct Item {
    var title: String
    var imageUrl: URL
    var mp3Url: URL
    init?(details: [String:Any]) {
        if let title = details["title"] as? String,
            let imageStr = details["image_url"] as? String,
            let imageUrl = URL(string: imageStr),
            let mp3Str = details["mp3"] as? String,
            let mp3Url = URL(string: mp3Str) {
                self.title = title
                self.imageUrl = imageUrl
                self.mp3Url = mp3Url
        } else { return nil }
    }
}
```

Then filter the array with the title property.

```
let playlistArray = [["title": "Kaṭha-Bhāṣyam-41 Mantra 1-2-20", "image_url": "https://...", "mp3": "https://..."],
                     ["title": "Kaṭha-Bhāṣyam-41 Mantra 1-2-20", "image_url": "https://...", "mp3": "https://..."],
                     ["title": "Kaṭha-Bhāṣyam-41 Mantra 1-2-20", "image_url": "https://...", "mp3": "https://..."]]
let playlistArr = playlistArray.compactMap(Item.init)
print(playlistArr)
let searchText = "Kar"//searchController.searchBar.text!
let filteredArray = playlistArr.filter({ $0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) })
print(filteredArray)
```